# Kubernetes: How I do I prevent an emptyDir from deleting all pre-exisitng files in a directory?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, volumes

I am mounting an `emptyDir` volume so it can be used for sharing files between containers running in the same pod. Lets say the mount point is called `/var/log/mylogs`. When I mount the `emptydir` all of the pre-existing files that were in mylogs get deleted. I know this is part of the Kubernetes functionality but I was wondering if there is a way to get around it? I [tried using subPath](https://medium.com/hackernoon/mount-file-to-kubernetes-pod-without-deleting-the-existing-file-in-the-docker-container-in-the-88b5d11661a6) but it looks like that only works for singular files.

Comment: The emptyDir volume type is ephemeral in nature as soon as the pod restart whatever stored on that path will get deleted. I would recommend to use the pvc and subPath.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar But will the pvc delete all of the existing contents? How would multiple files work with the subPath?

Comment: does this path `/var/log/mylogs` exist on the host (worker node) or only your pod?

Comment: @gohm'c I believe its in the pod only

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `PersistentVolumes` instead, since it serves as a long-term storage in your Kubernetes cluster. They exist beyond containers, pods, and nodes. A pod uses a persistent volume claim to to get read and write access to the persistent volume. `PersistentVolume` decouples the storage from the Pod. Its lifecycle is independent. It enables safe pod restarts and sharing data between pods.

> But will the pvc delete all of the existing contents? How would multiple files work with the subPath?

Forget about finding any workaround using emptryDir or SubPath when you can easily use `PersistentVolumes`. Data persistence — a mechanism that keeps data even after the Pod is deleted — is required.

You can find more useful info about `PersistentVolumes` on [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) or [here in a fresh new article](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-persistent-volumes-examples-and-best-practices/)